# IRC and SASL Authentication

Tags: irc, sasl

I'm building an IRC client and am currently attempting to add SASL support. I have got it working just fine (authentication works), however, there's an annoying "glitch":

As I've understood, the SASL request must be done BEFORE registration, like so:

```
if (sasl) {
    send("CAP REQ :sasl");
}
send("NICK: " + nick);
send("USER ....");
```

Now the annoying little thing is that the SASL request causes the IRC server to send back an ERR_NOTREGISTERED (451) reply. Now I could of course just ignore the very first 451 reply if SASL is enabled, but that seems a bit nasty. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, SASL on IRC is based on the [Client CAPability Negotiation](http://ircv3.atheme.org/specification/capability-negotiation-3.1).

According to this specification you send a `CAP LS` at the beginning, after this you send the `USER` and `NICK`. If you recive a `CAP` response before the end of the motd/motd missing, the server supports CAP. Check if SASL is on the list of supported extensions, and request it.
If you get the end of motd/motd missing first, the server does not support CAP, and therefore does not support SASL.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I ended up simply ignoring all ERR_NOTREGISTERED replies before registration if SASL is enabled.